# How to rename Hashtag via Yammer REST API

Tags: yammer

I know we have 'Rename Topic' link on the AboutTopic page which we can rename Hashtag name.
I want to know the programmatic way to do.
I confirmed REST API, but it looks like there is no specific API to do.
Let me know anything if you know about it, please!

Answer (score 0):

There is no API provided to rename tags or topics, or plan to add this, at the time of writing.